# create rules array based on a product variations array

Tags: php, arrays

I have this product variations array:

```
array:3 [
  0 => array:2 [
    0 => "2_12"
    1 => "4_9"
  ]
  1 => array:2 [
    0 => "2_3"
    1 => "4_9"
  ]
  2 => array:2 [
    0 => "2_4"
    1 => "4_10"
  ]
]
```

and need to create some rules from it.

Each array contain a product variation and each element is made from option_value.

ex: the first array: [2_12, 4_9] => [color_purple, material_cotton]

I want to create another array that contains each element combination based on that array.

ex: I want to see color_purple (2_12) what materials is combined with, material_cotton what colors is combined with...and so on.

Like this:

```
array:5 [
  "2_12" => array:1 [
    0 => "4_9"    
  ]
  "2_3" => array:1 [   
    0 => "4_9"
  ]
  "2_4" => array:1 [    
    0 => "4_10"
  ]
  "4_9" => array:2 [    
    0 => "2_12"
    1 => "2_3"
  ]
  "4_10" => array:1 [    
    0 => "2_4"
  ]
]
```

How to crate this last array based on the product variations array?

Comment: I think I would make my first attempt by coding a foreach loop over the original array

Comment: @RiggsFolly I posted a possible answer ... like I said it's not the best. Do you have a better solution ?

Answer (score 1):

I created the array ..... probably not the best solution ...but works.

Still if you got a better approach .... just post it :)

Based on the variations array:

```
    $rules = array();
    foreach ($variations as $variation) {
        foreach ($variation as $index => $v) {
            $nextIndex = ++$index;
            if(!isset($rules[$v])){
                $rules[$v] = array();
                if(isset($variation[$nextIndex])){
                   array_push($rules[$v],$variation[$nextIndex]);
                }
            } else {
                if(isset($variation[$nextIndex])){
                    array_push($rules[$v],$variation[$nextIndex]);
                }
            }
        }

        $variation = array_reverse($variation);
        foreach ($variation as $index => $v) {
            $nextIndex = ++$index;
            if(isset($variation[$nextIndex])){
                array_push($rules[$v],$variation[$nextIndex]);
            }
        }
    }
```

and the rules array looks like this:

```
array:5 [
  "2_12" => array:1 [
    0 => "4_9"
  ]
  "4_9" => array:2 [
    0 => "2_12"
    1 => "2_3"
  ]
  "2_3" => array:1 [
    0 => "4_9"
  ]
  "2_4" => array:1 [
    0 => "4_10"
  ]
  "4_10" => array:1 [
    0 => "2_4"
  ]
]
```